# Law of large numbers for Harris recurrent Markov chains

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

I'm trying to familiarize myself with the details of the proof that the Markov chains produce by the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm have a law of large numbers. I've found a half dozen or more references to the proof in Meyn, Tweedie and Glynn's book. I believe that I follow most of it, but I'm not sure on some of the step in one part of the proof where they prove that a certain function is harmonic.

I realize that this may not be research level, but I have had problems finding alternative treatments because everyone cites this!

Here is the relevant section:[image]

Here is my "understanding" of the steps working from the bottom:

To go from 4 to 3 involves a re-expression of $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k = 1}^n g(\Phi_k)$.

To go from 3 to 2, one applies the "smoothing property of conditional expectation". In the process the $g(\Phi_1)/n$ term vanishes because the numerator becomes a constant.

To go from 2 to 1 follows from the Markov property. Starting from $x$ and conditioning on $\Phi_1$ is like starting at $\Phi_1$. This is reflected in the conditioning on $\mathcal{F}^{\Phi}_1$ being dropped and $\mathrm{P}_x$ becoming $\mathrm{P}_{\Phi_1}$.

Where I am getting lost is in the indexing changes between steps. I keep thinking perhaps the index in the subscript in step 3 should maybe be $k$ rather than $k+1$ or that the minus sign out to be a plus sign.

If anyone could expand upon or annotated the steps in this derivation I'd be very grateful. Apologies if this is trivial (I sort of hope it is!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument given in the book is actually quite misleading. It is much easier just to notice that the event $\{S_n/n\to \langle g,\pi\rangle \}$ from the definition of the function $g_\infty$ is (time shift) invariant, and therefore this function is harmonic by Theorem 17.1.3.

Comment: Oh my god, thank you! I kept thinking exactly what you said, and didn't quite understand what 17.1.6 was adding, but that's the one that everyone cites, so I thought maybe I was missing some technical detail, but then I had trouble tracking their indicies...I thought I was going insane.